# Django Need to add two serializers data together in one response

Tags: django

I have a two models, Person and Video.

Below viewset allows me all methods like POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET.

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = apis_models.Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = apis_serializers.PersonSerializer
    permission_classes = [HasPermPage]
```

Video model is associated with person model through Target model which is my main problem. Each person has few videos.

Now what I need is when I do "/person/{id}/" I should get person details along with all videos details it associated with.

Please let me know what change needs to be done to above ViewSet.

Models and Serializer:

```
class Video(DFModel):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, models.DO_NOTHING)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Creator, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    views = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    page_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    video_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    thumb_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sfw = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    organization_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    active_scraping = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    vuln_score = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    reviewed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

class Target(DFModel):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.ForeignKey(
        'Video', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'target'

class PersonSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.Person
        fields = '__all__'

class TargetSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.Target
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['monthly_growth', 'vulnerablility_score']

class VideoSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    source = SourceSerializer(read_only=True)
    creator = CreatorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.Video
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Where's your model `Creator`?

Comment: Model Creator do not have any relation in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a ManyToMany relation between Person and Video, so, I suggest you to change your models to be like:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    active_scraping = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    vuln_score = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    reviewed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video, through='Target', related_name="people") # Field that will have the videos of a Person
```

Once you have that, I suggest you to change your PersonSerializer object to be:

```py
class PersonSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    videos = VideoSerializer(source='videos', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

If you can't change your models to support ManyToMany fields I suggest you to do the following:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    active_scraping = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    vuln_score = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    reviewed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def videos(self):
        return Video.objects.filter(
            id__in=Target.objects.filter(person=self).values('video')
        )
```

And use the same serializer I used in the first part of the answer.